# Element from a formal power series that is algebraic over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I don't know how I should solve this exercise:

> The polynomial ring $K[T]$, and hence also its field of fractions $K(T)$, is a subring of $K((T))$. Give an example, for some field $K$ , of an element $a \in K (( T )) $  with $ a \not\in K(T)$, such that is algebraic over $K ( T )$

I know that I have to search for a field and an element that is root of minimalpolynomial in that field but not an element of the field itself. For example $i \not\in \mathbb{R}$ but $f(x)=x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{R}$ . But I don't know any example that is in the formal power series $K((T))$ but not in the field itself solving the algebraic condition. 
I'm thankful for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I read the question we are free to choose the field $K$. Just in case I misunderstood, I proffer an example for all fields. To that end it suffices to cover all the prime fields $\Bbb{Q}, \Bbb{F}_p$, $p$ a prime number.

Recall [the binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) of $\sqrt{1+T}$ (=its Taylor series centered at the origin) from calculus. Its coefficients are rational, so this works for any field $K$ of characteristic zero.

If $K$ has characteristic $p>2$, then you can first show that the coefficients of the series of $\sqrt{1+4T}$ are all integers, and thus make sense modulo $p$.

If $K$ has characteristic $p=2$, then apply freshman's dream to the series
$$
a=T+T^2+T^4+T^8+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty T^{2^k}
$$
to show that $a+a^2=T$. Mind you, this series has a counterpart for all $p$, so you can skip the integrality property in the previous suggestion, and use that instead.

Comment: In my $p=2$  suggestion it is not entirely trivial to show that $a$ is not in $K(T)$. The first idea that occurs to me would be to show that the series representations of all elements of $K(T)$ are eventually periodic. You may have done this in class already.

Comment: Suppose $a \in \mathbf{F}_2(T)$. There are infinitely many $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbf{F}_2}$ such that the roots of $x + x^2 = \alpha$ do not lie in $\mathbf{F}_2(\alpha)$. At least one of them is not in the denominator of $a$. Evaluating $a + a^2 = T$ at $T=\alpha$ then gives a contradiction.

Comment: Nice idea, Hurkyl!